# Ruby Rails Sort Index List of users by most recent review

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of users that post reviews.  I'm trying to make the list sortable in different ways.  I'm stuck on sorting the list by each user's most recent review.

My current approach is to make a model scope.  I'm just not getting it.

This is the model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :password
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :user_name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  before_save :encrypt_password
  
  has_many :reviews
  has_one_attached :avatar_pic


  scope :users_most_recent, -> {(
    select('users.id, users.user_name')
    .joins(:reviews).where('reviews.updated_at')
    .group('users.id')
    .order('updated_at DESC')
    )}


  def self.user_reviews(user_id)
    @user_reviews = Review.where(user_id: user_id).count
  end

  def self.user_ave_rating(user_id)
    _average_reviews = []
    _rev_count = 0
    _new_average = 0.0
    _average_reviews = Review.where(user_id: user_id)
    _average_reviews.each do |average_review|
      _rev_count += average_review.rating
    end
    _new_average = (_rev_count / _average_reviews.length.to_f).round(1)
  end

  def self.user_latest_review(user_id)
    @latest_review = Review.where(user_id: user_id).where('created_at < ? ', Time.now).order('created_at DESC').first
    if @latest_review.nil?
      last_review = {}
      else
        last_review = @latest_review.created_at.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
    self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password,password_salt)
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = User.find_by "email = ?", email
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

end
```

This is the controller, the index is where I'm trying to implement this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :current_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.avatar_pic.attach(params[:user][:avatar_pic])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You've successfully signed up!"
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to "/"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "There was a problem signing up."
      redirect_to '/signup'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = current_user
    render :show
  end  

  def edit
    @user = current_user
    render :edit
  end  

  def update
    @user = current_user

    if @user.update(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Profile successfully updated!"
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      render :edit
      flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong. Please contact Mario's technical assistance staff."
    end
  end

  def index
    case
    when params[:az]
      @users = User.order('user_name').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    when params[:za]
      @users = User.order('user_name DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    when params[:high_rating]
      "High Rating"
    when params[:low_rating]
      "Low Rating"
    when params[:most_reviews]
      "Most Reviews"
    when params[:least_reviews]
      "Least Reviews"
    when params[:most_recent]
      @users = User.users_most_recent.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    when params[:least_recent]
      "Least Recent"
    else
      @users = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    end
    render :index
  end
  
  

  private
  
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :user_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :admin, :avatar_pic)
  end
end
```

This is my view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class="sort-flex-wrapper">
  <h1 class="center">Our Community</h1>

  <div class="btn-group sort-button">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Sort By
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">

      <%= link_to "User Name A-Z", users_path(:az => 'az'), class: "dropdown-item" %>
      <%= link_to "User Name Z-A", users_path(:za => 'za'), class: "dropdown-item" %>
      <%= link_to "Highest Average Rating", users_path(:high_rating => 'high_rating'), class: "dropdown-item" %>
      <%= link_to "Lowest Average Rating", users_path(:low_rating => 'low_rating'), class: "dropdown-item" %>
      <%= link_to "Most Reviews", users_path(:most_reviews => 'most_reviews'), class: "dropdown-item" %>
      <%= link_to "Least Reviews", users_path(:least_reviews => 'least_reviews'), class: "dropdown-item" %>
      <%= link_to "Most Recent Review", users_path(:most_recent => 'most_recent'), class: "dropdown-item" %>
      <%= link_to "Least Recent Review", users_path(:least_recent => 'least_recent'), class: "dropdown-item" %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="community-flex-container">
  <% if @users.any? %>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>

      <div class="community-profile-card">
        <div class="community-profile-flex">

          <div class="community-profile-box1">
            <% if user.avatar_pic.attached? %>
              <%= image_tag user.avatar_pic, class:"avatar" %><br>
              <% else %>
                <%= image_tag 'generc_profile_pic.webp', class:"avatar", alt: 'Avatar Not Found ' %><br>
            <% end %>
          </div>

          <div class="community-profile-box2">
            <div class="community-column-box1">
              <% if user.user_name? %>
                <h3><%= user.user_name %></h3>
                <% else %>
                <h3>Guest User</h3>
              <% end %>
            </div>

            <div class="community-column-box2">
              <div class="community-align-stars"> 
                <p>Average Rating: </p>              
              </div>
              <div class="community-align-stars">
                <div class="star-align">
                  <%= render partial: "shared/review_stars", locals: { review: User.user_ave_rating(user.id) } %>
                </div>
              </div>                  
            </div>

            <div class="community-column-box3">
              <p>Number of Reviews: <%= User.user_reviews(user.id) %></p>
            </div>

            <div class="community-column-box4">
              <% if User.user_latest_review(user.id) == {} %>
                <p>Most Recent Review: None</p>
                <% else %>
                  <p>Most Recent Review: <%= User.user_latest_review(user.id) %></p>
              <% end %>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 

    <% end %>

  <% else %>
    <p>There are no users (yet).</p>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="pagination">
  <%= will_paginate @reviews%>
</div>
```

Comment: So what isn't working with what you did?

Comment: Currently, I'm getting a crash with this message: 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Users#index

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type timestamp without time zone
LINE 1: ...ews" ON "reviews"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (reviews.up...

Comment: Yes the where in your query makes no sense, I removed it in my answer. What was the where's purpose?

Comment: I'm way over my head.  It was a flailing approach.

Comment: No worries. I hope it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope :users_most_recent, -> {(
    select('users.id, users.user_name, max(reviews.updated_at) as reviews_updated_at')
    .joins(:reviews)
    .group('users.id')
    .order('reviews_updated_at')
    )}
```

Comment: Thank you Joel!  It's not crashing now (yay!), but the dates aren't in order.

Comment: Yep, so I"m adding .order.  I think you solved my problem

Comment: Hmm they should already be ordered on the latest review...

Comment: Yep and my messing with ordered didn't help me.  Most of the dates are from the database seed.  But I have made some reviews manually for some users and they aren't displaying in any order.  Is there a file you want to see?  Something I'm overlooking?

Comment: What should be ordered is the users yes? According to the latest review each user made. So what are you seeing exactly, are the users not ordered according to the latest review?

Comment: About 90% of my users were seeded on March 30th and so are all their reviews.  There are about a dozen that I have logged into or that have newer posts.  In this latest sort, I see the first paginated page full of 3-30 posts and also on the last page

Comment: When I look for the latest posts, i find them randomly mixed in.  I can verify that I have not posted any new reviews for any of the first page users or last page users.

Comment: I added my view, above, in case that helps.  The intention was to show users listed by most recent review posted (I was thinking updated_at).  So a user who posted today would be at the first of the list, and so on to the least recently posted user.

Comment: @DrewPeterson7671 Ah OK, you need an ordering on the reviews.updated_at as well

Answer (score 1):

Well, while we're at it we might as well fix the whole index method. You're doing to much in the controller, split it out to something like this:

```
class UserList
  def self.order_users_by(order_value)
    case order_value
    when :az
      User.order('user_name ASC')
    when :za
      User.order('user_name DESC')
    when :high_rating
      User.all.sort_by(&:average_rating).reverse
    when :low_rating
      User.all.sort_by(&:average_rating)
    when :most_reviews
      User.all.sort_by(&:review_count).reverse
    when :least_reviews
      User.all.sort_by(&:review_count)
    else
      User.all.sort_by(&:last_updated_review)
    end
  end
end

class User   
  def average_rating
    (BigDecimal(reviews.sum(:rating).to_s) / BigDecimal(reviews.count.to_s)).round(1)
  end

  def review_count
    reviews.count
  end

  def last_updated_review
    reviews.order("updated_at")
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    UserList.order_users_by(params).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
  end
end
```

Comment: This actually solves several things I had to work out.  Thank you!

Comment: I had a couple of questions if you don't mind.  I looked up BigDecimal, very interesting.  Why to_s on those?

Comment: Glad to help. Because BigDecimals only takes in strings, it ensures that when you're calculating with decimal values, the answere is precise. You should never calculate with float values, the answere won't be accurate. You can read about it by googling it or read here https://dzone.com/articles/never-use-float-and-double-for-monetary-calculatio

Comment: I always have gone with a @users and render index. How does this new User class not conflict on other Rails CRUD functionality.  LIke User.new for Create method?

Comment: Nono, the User class is the same as user model with active record. I just scratched up the methods I was going to add.